# How to fetch Session variable value from a controller to ajax call in c# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I want to fetch Session variable value from an mvc controller actionresult which returns a cshtml view. This ajax call is connected in a  button click and is calling from a different cshtml.

```
function accountLogin() {
$.ajax({
    url: accountLogin,
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var testUser = @Session[Keys.accountrole];
        alert(testUser);
        $("#navigationbar").empty();
        $("#navigationbar").html(data);}
```

C# Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult accountLogin(){
        Session[Keys.accountrole] = "value";
        return View("_viewpage");
    }
```

The curent implementation is reaturning either undefined session variable  or it will display the @session keyword itself not the value in it.

Comment: If you want to return a value from your controller - why are you returning a view? You should probably return JSON, which is very easy to work with in JavaScript.

Comment: @mason  other than json is there any oher way to pass the value as I need to store the value either in viewbag or session

Comment: Why must you store it in ViewBag or Session?

Comment: @mason  to reuse the value

Comment: Make the session JavaScript: '@Session["Keys.accountrol"]';

Comment: That does not make sense. If you need to store something in your session, you're already doing that. Putting something in a ViewBag is only needed if you're using a View, and it's not clear that you need a View here at all. And even if you are, you should use a Model rather than ViewBag to pass data from a Controller to a View.

Comment: @mason I want to use this session value to check something in the ajax call itself.And also the returning cshtml is another view and it is not depend on the ajax call.When this actionresult return the view at the same time I need to fetch the value from actionresult

Comment: @GHDevOps I already tried this and it results the entire variable itself not the value in it

Comment: You say the other view isn't dependent on the AJAX call - then why are you returning it from your controller? If the only thing your AJAX call needs to obtain is the value from Session[Keys.accountrole] on the server side, then have your controller return that value wrapped in JSON.

Comment: @mason  The other view is an existng implementation that I dont want to touch .Instead I need to call an ajax and fetch the value from the same action result.

Comment: Well a method can only return one object. So if you must return a view, and you need to return some extra value in that view, you could potentially embed that value in a hidden input field in the view, and then have the JavaScript extract it from there once retrieved on the server. It's a bit of an ugly approach, but I don't have a better suggestion since what you're doing is still not very clear.

Comment: @mason I will check someother options to implement the same.Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access Session on the server side. So you have to get a Session variable value inside of the action and retun it back as  a json value

Try this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult accountLogin(){

        //I don't understand why you need it
        Session[Keys.accountrole] = "value";

        var sessionAccountRole=Session[Keys.accountrole];

        return OK( {accountRole=sessionAccountRole} );

        // or if you use an ancient net 
        return Json ( new {accountRole=sessionAccountRole} );

       // or maybe 
   return new JsonResult {accountRole=sessionAccountRole};
    }
```

and ajax

```
  success: function (data) {
        var testUser = data.accountRole;
        alert(testUser);
```

Comment: @mason Thanks, I added possible variants

Comment: This method wont work for me ,but thanks for your support

Comment: @codehunter Then nothing can work for you unfortunately.